# How to get the values of an object in Typescript

Tags: typescript

How to
I know how to get the keys of an object. But how to get the values of an object?

```js
const Obj  = {
  A: 'A1',
  B: 'B2',
  C: 'C3'
}

type keys = keyof typeof Obj; // 'A' | 'B' | 'C'
type values = ??? // 'A1' | 'B2' | 'C3'
```

It only outputs 'string': `typeof Obj[keyof typeof Obj]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare `Obj` as const:

```
const Obj  = {
  A: 'A1',
  B: 'B2',
  C: 'C3'
} as const
```